# What, intuitively, are supernatural numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers

Before I can get to grips with something rigorously I need to understand it in an intuitive way.  I was trying to get my head around the [supernatural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernatural_number).  Looking at the definition it looks like they could extend the conventional numbers, by placing them in union with something analogous to the residues of the p-adics.  Is this a fair description?

Comment: Are supernatural numbers anything more that elements of ${\mathbb N}^{\mathbb N}$ for which you look at the componentwise mulitplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To better comprehend supernatural (or Steinitz) numbers it is illuminating to examine the various contexts in which they arise naturally. For example, see the equivalent conditions $(c)-(i)$ listed below (excerpted from [here)](https://books.google.com/books?id=MMOlSR5oKWgC&lpg=PA223&ots=rvgPTazoe7&dq=steinitz%20supernatural%20subgroup%20rational&pg=PA223#v=onepage&q=approximatively&f=false).

**Note** $ $ Said descriptions are independent of the first three introductory paragraphs on locally simple algebras, so you can skip them if such algebras are not of interest (start reading at the paragraph "One can observe that ...")

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow that is some pretty heavy reading!

Comment: @RobertFrost I suggest you start first with relation to subgoups of the additive group or rationals (d), which is perhaps the simplest.

Comment: Ok I will read.  In the p-adics, $p^1$ is represented as a 1 carried up from the 1st digit. $p^2$ is a $1$ carried up from the 2nd digit and so on.  If there's some arbitrarily large number $a$ such that $n\leq a\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ and we say $0=\overline9+1$ then zero in the p-adics is equivalent to $p^a$.  Zero in the p-adics therefore would seem to be equal to a 1 carried up from the $(a-1)^{th}$ digit to the $a^{th}$. The p-adics are therefore equivalent modulo $p^{a-1}$...

Comment: Based on my (incorrect?) interpretation of the supernaturals, these extend the naturals by exactly these numbers $p^x:x\geq a$, which are the modulus under which the p-adics are equivalent.  I think that's my question better formulated.  is that a correct intuitive description of them?

Comment: @RobertFrost In what context did you encounter supernaturals?

Comment: I just stumbled upon the fact that they extend the notion of compound numbers except with possibly infinite powers of each prime, and I'm interested in p-adic arithmetic so I was hoping for a quick, intuitive understanding of how they might be related and useful. My intuition says $2^\infty$ is supernatural and all $2$-adics are equivalent $\pm 2^{\infty}$.

Comment: @RobertFrost Could you please give some links to the expositions that you seek to better understand.

Comment: It's my own exposition.  My logic is this.  When we move, in the p-adics, from $\overline9$ to $0$, by the addition of $1$, we might imagine we have carried the $(p-1)*p^{\infty}$ to $p^{\infty+1}$, so the $p$-adics are equivalent $p^{\infty}$ where $p^{\infty}$ is a supernatural number.  And that is why $p$-adics are so powerful.

Answer (score 3):

The set of supernatural numbers is an extension to the set of natural numbers:

- The factorization of a natural number must contain a finite number of primes
- The factorization of a supernatural number may contain an infinite number of primes

Comment: Oh ok but not necessarily infinite. Let me be more precise in my question.

Comment: @RobertFrost: Yes, that's what I meant to say.