# Should infinite order elements not be called zero order elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For a unital ring $R$, there is a homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow R$ and the kernel is an ideal of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$ for unique $n\in \mathbb{N}$, which we call the characteristic of the ring.

In a similar kind of way, for a group $G$, and $g\in G$ there is a homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G$ sending $n$ to $g^n$. The kernel of this homomorphism is again of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$ for unique $n\in \mathbb{N}$ which we call the order of $g\in G$, except for when $n=0$ and then we say $g$ has infinite order.

Wouldn't it be better to say $g$ has order zero in this case, for consistency?

Comment: I think it would be better to use "characteristic $\infty$".  After all, that gives the size of the additive cyclic subgroup $\langle 1 \rangle$.

Comment: The order of $g\in G$ is the infimum of $\{n\in {\mathbb N}: g^n=1\}$. Now, the infimum of an empty subset of ${\mathbb R}$ is usually declared to be infinity. One more thing: In English, $0$ is not an element of ${\mathbb N}$.

Comment: For me $0\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @MoisheKohan Whether $0$ is a natural number is not a question of language, but of the whims of the particular mathematician writing, and often depends more on which choice is more convenient in the given context (unlike whether $0$ is a positive number, which does depend on language).

Comment: I have voted to close this as "opinion-based".

Comment: Where is a good place to ask this kind of question if not here?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: It s not matter of language but of mathematical tradition. In English mathematical tradition, natural numbers start with $1$, while in French, they start with $0$. Ditto for neighborhoods: In French they are not required to be open while in English they are.

Comment: What you say makes sense, but it is only one view. The other view is that the order of $g\in G$ is the order of the cyclic subgroup $\langle g\rangle$. I see no reason why we should adopt either view over the other.

Comment: @Moishe As someone who was UK-educated and has only ever worked in UK maths departments, I find that the reality of this tradition is closer to what Tobias describes (possibly because when you write maths in English you do not expect your readers to be native English speakers and so be aware of such traditions).

Comment: "elements of finite order" would mean all elements, if this were adopted.

Comment: @rschwieb but we'd then use "torsion elements" instead, which is relatively established.

Comment: @user1729 I'm not sure why or how one would eradicate a well-used term (in the context of $\mathbb Z$-modules) just to adopt this convention.

Comment: @rschwieb I agree :-)

Comment: @rschwieb, concerning elements of finite order, this would become elements of non-zero order though

Comment: @JoshuaTilley It’s an alternative... but not an improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a situation where this convention is useful. Suppose we have a group homomorphism $f : G \to H$ and let $a$ be in $G$. What is the order of $f(a)$ in $H$? In general, $f$ need not preserve order (just consider the constant map $f(a) = 1$), but what's true is that $\operatorname{ord}_H(f(a))$ must be a divisor of $\operatorname{ord}_G(a)$. If we set $\operatorname{ord}(a) = 0$ for elements of "infinite" order, then, keeping in mind that everything divides 0 while 0 divides only 0, this divisibility relation shows that homomorphic images of elements of infinite order can have arbitrary order, while no element of finite order can map to an element of infinite order.

Comment: Nice observation!

Answer (score 1):

The nomenclature for an infinite order element of a group is not in terms of the kernel of the relevant homomorphism, but rather the order of the cyclic subgroup generated by the element. For rings, they went with the nonnegative generator of the kernel of the homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to R$, though this is not explicit in the usual definition (which is inconsistent, saying the characteristic is the minimal positive integer such that $n1=0$, then giving $0$ as an exception when no such integer exists).

One could argue that the subgroup concept makes more sense for general groups because it is given in terms of the order of a group, whereas the kernel definition is additive which is appropriate for the additive group of a ring.

Comment: Maybe for rings it has more to do with the kernel of $\mathbb Z\to R$.

Comment: @rschwieb You're probably right, and I just realized that's in the question. I edited my answer,

Comment: In the case of rings, we can also define the characteristic to be the order of the subring generated by the homomorphism though, so no real asymmetry.

Comment: @JoshuaTilley If we defined it that way the characteristic would be infinity instead of $0$.

Comment: Yes, it would be a different convention, but a more consistent one

Comment: @JoshuaTilley If you think about it, though, we really care about when the result is $0$ for rings. Characteristic infinity wouldn't tell you anything about when it is $0$. Characteristic $0$ means it's $0$ only for $n=0$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand

Comment: @JoshuaTilley I'm just saying it's really the kernel we care about for rings, not the order of the subring.

Comment: The kernel is $n\mathbb{Z}$ iff the image, i.e. the subring, is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, so either tells us the same.

Comment: @JoshuaTilley But the kernel is $\{0\}$ if the image is infinite. They are not equivalent.

Comment: The two conventions amount to interchanging $0$ and $\infty$, that is all, they tell us the same thing

Comment: @JoshuaTilley See [supernatural numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1893018/242)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's harmless to call such elements of order zero; probably it's been done occasionally. If for some reason it's practical (e.g., you talk of elements of order $n$ and $n$ can be zero), just say it at the beginning.

Actually it's "almost" done somewhere: the characteristic of a unital ring $R$ is by definition the order of $1$ in $(R,+)$... and one says "characteristic zero", and (almost?) never "infinite characteristic".